# Unable to optimise Redshift query

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have build a system where data is loaded from s3 into redshift every few minutes (from a kinesis firehose). I then grab data from that main table and split it into a table per customer.

The main table has a few hundred million rows.

creating the subtable is done with a query like this:

```
create table {$table} as select * from {$source_table} where customer_id = '{$customer_id} and time between {$start} and {$end}'
```

I have keys defined as:

```
SORTKEY (customer_id, time)
DISTKEY customer_id
```

Everything I have read suggests this would be the optimal way to structure my tables/queries but the performance is absolutely awful. building the sub tables takes over a minute even with only a few rows to select.

Am I missing something or do I just need to scale the cluster?

Comment: Are those DISTKEY and SORTKEYs on the main table, or the sub-table? If you run the query as a SELECT rather than as CREATE TABLE, then how long does it take to execute?

Comment: SELECT and CREATE TABLE are nearly identical performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have a better key you may have to consider using `DISTSTYLE EVEN`, keeping the same sort key.

Ideally the distribution key should be a value that is used in joins and spreads your data evenly across the cluster. By using `customer_id` as the distribution key and then filtering on that key you're forcing all work to be done on just one slice.

To see this in action look in the system tables. First, find an example query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM stl_query 
WHERE userid > 1 
ORDER BY starttime DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

Then, look at the `bytes` per slice for each step of you query in `svl_query_report`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM svl_query_report 
WHERE query = <your query id> 
ORDER BY query,segment,step,slice;
```

For a very detailed guide on designing the best table structure have a look at our ["Amazon Redshift Engineering’s Advanced Table Design Playbook"](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/amazon-redshift-engineerings-advanced-table-design-playbook-preamble-prerequisites-and-prioritization/)

Comment: This makes sense, I'll experiment with even distribution to see that improves performance.